# How to get rid of a duplicate title on the front page?

Tags: 7, nodes

When I first made the front page, I created a Basic Page and selected "Promoted to Front Page" and thought I was done.  Drupal insisted on showing this page as an article summary, and no manner of tweaking settings on my part prevented this behavior.  I decided instead to put the main front page content in a block because it will seldom ever change.

I created my block, and yay!  No more summarized front page content.  However, the title of the page shows twice.  The first is the title of the original basic page I created, the second is the title of the block I created.  I've already cleared the cache and there was no change.

How do I get rid of the duplicate?

Comment: What does your page.tpl.php file look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have `node` as your front page which lists summaries of content that is promoted to the front page by default. That's the way Drupal comes configured out of the box. If I understand correctly, what you're looking for though is a single node to be displayed in full on the front page.

You can change it from `node` (which shows a list) to your specific Node at `admin/config/system/site-information` or Configuration -> Site Information under the "Front Page" section. Simply change "node" to "node/[node-id]" where [node-id] = the nid of the node you want to appear on the front page:

[image: Front Page Promotion]

Comment: This the solution I was looking for in the first place before setting up a block.  It's been ages since I've had to set up a Drupal website and I missed this.  Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

I will address your situation by telling you both the solution to your previous problem, followed by your current conundrum.

The "promoted to front page" option is intended to be a list of several things (think of the front page of a blog).  If you want a single front page, then change the settings for the front page (under `admin/config/system/site-information`).  It is currently set to "node", which is a list of everything that is "promoted to the front page".  Instead, change it to "node/#" (where "#" is the number of the node itself).

The other option is the way that you did it.  It works, but as you see, it's a bit of a kludge.  You can hide the title of the block by editing the block contents.  There are 2 titles, so to speak.  One is used for identification on the block administration page (the description), and one is for display (the title).  Just leave the title blank.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to keep the block as your page content rather than setting a node to be displayed as the front page, there are a few ways to get rid of the title on the front page.  Preferably using CSS since you don't have a H1 anywhere else on the page.

```
.front .page__title {
  display: none;
}
```

Or you could remove it completely by duplicating your themes `page.tpl.php` > removing the line that prints the page title > saving it to your templates folder as `page--front.tpl.php`

Comment: I didn't wish to keep the block, but did it because I didn't initially see the option to set a single node as the front page.  Thanks anyway. :)